# Print HTML From Url

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urlopen

So I  want to print out the `HTML` of a website

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

http = urlopen('http://www.google.de/').read()
print(http)
```

But in the output all newlines are printed as `\n` and the string begins with a b' which has something to do with a bite array as my google research told me? sorry I'm new to python xD

So my question is how can i print the html code as a normal string with newlines as it would be shown in a text editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) documentation. In the HTML header it is written `charset=UTF-8`. You therefore need to change your line to:

```
print(http.decode('utf-8'))
```

In case you have special characters in the HTML output (due to locale settings), use:

```
print(http.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore'))
```